# Progress circle css is broken with flexbox align-items center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I copied the progress circle css from an online source. The progress circle is perfect if it is in a div with only one line:

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <div class="progress-circle"><div>
    <div>Some short text</div>
</div>
```

But becomes broken if it is a div with more than two lines:

```
<div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
    <div class="progress-circle"><div>
    <div>Some long text which wraps to the next line</div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. I don't understand the progress circle css in the first place (though I've tried). Can someone explain what is happening and why it's happening?

Edit: I simplified the progress-circle html a bit. The actual progress-circle html is:

```
<div class="c100 $progress">
    <div class="slice">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="fill"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Broken progress circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guou1.png)

[Progress circle css](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n85iji81f3urlfj/circle.css?dl=0)

Comment: Add `flex-shrink: 0` to your progress circle. This will disable the `flex-shrink: 1` default.

Comment: Didn't work :( I added it as inline-style to the outer div first. When that didn't work, I added it to the inner div also. Still didn't work. The progress circle changed from being too thin on the right to being too thin on the bottom in both cases though.

Comment: You should post enough code in your question to reproduce the problem.